# how to replace all html tag of a html file using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am extracting a file using `$data = file_get_contents("file.html");`

I want to replace all html tags from `$data` using a specified string (e.g : `\n`) . I can do this for a single line not for entire data .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the source code for how you're currently doing it unsuccessfully?

Comment: are you stripping all tags and only keeping the string? In which case what about title, or footer data? Just throwing that out there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this

```
echo preg_replace('#\<(.*?)\>(.*?)\</(.*?)\>#', '[\\1]--[\\2]--[/\\3]', $data);
```

and change the second parameter.

This would turn

`<b>This text is bold</b>` to `[b]--This text is bold--[/b]`

`\\1` returns the tag (in the opening brackets), `\\2` returns whatever was in between the tags and `\\3` returns the tag again (in the closing brackets)

Try playing around with it

EDIT: If you want to replace all HTML tags with `\n`, then do this

```
echo preg_replace('#\<(.*?)\>#', '\n', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do but to remove all html tags you could use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: I want to replace all html tags using "\n"

Comment: You mean something that `<b>\nfoo\n</b>` gets `foo` or `<b>foo</b>`?

Answer (score 1):

what about using `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` or you could to use `highlight_string()` or `highlight_file()`